how to create a cloudwatch alarm to check if azure devops agent is running in all AWS EC2 instances in an AWS Auto scaling group
Can someone guide me how I can create a cloudwatch alarm to check if azure devops agent is running in all AWS EC2 instances in an AWS Auto scaling group?
thank you!
I already tried to do it using UI but I am not sure what to choose.
